# sonar code smell for reducer used in combineReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, sonarqube

I am using combineReducer to combine reducers and reducer like this

```
const todo = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    //...

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state
      }

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        completed: !state.completed
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

My problem is if i am defining reducer like that i am getting sonar code smell

```
Function parameters with default values should be last1
```

but combine reducer pass argument in this sequence only how to work on this?

Answer (score 6):

we did have the same issue within our project, and sonar allows you to define exclusions for rules and files in `Administration -> Congifuration -> Analysis Scope`.

you will find there a section called `Ignore issues on Multiple Criteria` and there you can enter the rule and a "file pattern" to exclude files from this rule.

like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the Sonarqube docs:

> Function parameters with default values should be last:
>
> ...But all function parameters with default values should be declared
>   after the function parameters without default values. Otherwise, it
>   makes it impossible for callers to take advantage of defaults; they
>   must re-specify the defaulted values or pass undefined in order to
>   "get to" the non-default parameters.

This does, however, work with Redux as it calls your reducer for the first time with `undefined` as the first argument. If you want to continue using this pattern, you'll need to disable the rule or skip that line from analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What if you define a default value for the second arg?

```
const todo = (state = {}, action = null/undefined) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Set action with `{}`:

for example, changing the below code

```
const todo = (state = {}, action) => { }
```

to this

```
const todo = (state = {}, action = {}) => { }
```

Will be the safest way.