# annotation to skip sonar analysis on a class

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint, sonarqube5.1

am having a class, which is giving me sonar issues.
That is just a temporary class and I would ignore it in future sprints. How can I mark that particular class to be ignored from sonar analysis, as we have guidelines to commit code only if no sonar issues found.

Comment: doesn't seem like a good idea. if you shouldn't commit code with Sonar issues, you probably also shouldn't go around them and suppress

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking you do have multiple options: (i assume you are using java, but there are equivalent solutions for other languages)

1. ignoring the whole class

   There is a property called `sonar.exclusion` which you can set to ignore that specific class. This needs to be set either your `sonar-project.properties` or based on the scanner you are using. For details take a look [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/)
2. ignoring just some lines with issues

   In the java world you can use line comments with `//NOSONAR <reason>` to exclude lines from detection. There are equivalents in other languages too.
3. ignoring just some issues on the class/method

   In Java you can use the `@SuppressWarnings("<rule id>")` to exclude issues from classes and methods for detection. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30383335/3708208
4. Define multiple ignore criteria for wildcard and rules

   you can also define special settings in sonarqube, to ignore special files and folders via wildcard input, and which rules should be ignored. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639382/3708208

Comment: I would like to add that you can also include that in the `build.gradle` by doing `sonarqube { properties { property 'sonar.exclusions', '**/file_to_exclude.java' } }`

Answer (score 0):

for those who use *SonarLint* plugin for *IntelliJ Idea*:

**File > Settings > Tools > SonarLint > File Exclusions**